# Have audio tag play after a delay?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-audio

I'm playing an MP3 using the `<audio>` tag in HTML5.

```
<audio controls="controls" autoplay="autoplay">
  <source src="song.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
</audio>
```

This works fine, but I am wondering how I can put a delay in before the song starts to autoplay? I know there's not a `delay` attribute, but I'm thinking it could be accomplished via javascript?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this, really simple but you should move the JS outside the markup...

```
<audio controls="controls" onloadeddata="var audioPlayer = this; setTimeout(function() { audioPlayer.play(); }, 8000)">
    <source src="Kalimba.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
</audio>
```

Comment: How to it auto display on mobile ?

Comment: Generally, audio and video tags in mobile browsers don't autoplay on mobile devices because of battery and network drain.

Comment: I know but you think whether have any solution for it?

Answer (score 7):

Javascript only method:

```js
var sound = document.createElement('audio')
sound.id = 'audio'
sound.controls = 'controls'
sound.src = 'http://a.tumblr.com/tumblr_leltkjNwWL1qf32t9o1.mp3'
sound.type = 'audio/mp3'
document.body.appendChild(sound)

function playAudio() {
  document.getElementById('audio').play();
}

setTimeout("playAudio()", 3000);
```

Comment: Would the 'audioElement' be the class name of the element?

Comment: Actually I made an edit use document.getElementById('audio').play(); instead.

Comment: You would need to add ID="audio" to the audio element.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

HTML:

```
<div id='audio'>This will be replaced with an audio tag</div>​
```

jQuery:​

```
$(document).ready(​function (){
    $("#audio").stop("true").delay('2000').queue(function() { 
      $(this).html('<audio controls="controls" autoplay="autoplay"><source src="song.mp3" type="audio/mp3" /></audio>');
    });
});​
```

All together would be:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='audio'>This will be replaced with an audio tag</div>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            $(document).ready(function (){
                $("#audio").stop("true").delay('2000').queue(function() { 
                    $(this).html('<audio controls="controls" autoplay="autoplay"><source src="song.mp3" type="audio/mp3" /></audio>');
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

You can use `.delay()` to delay a process in jQuery.
The time is in milliseconds, so 2000 = 2 seconds.

Comment: That wouldn't work exactly as planned... it's calling the stop method that belongs to jquery and not to the audio API.