# How do I get the sleep function to respond appropriately in a for loop in PHP

Tags: php, audio, for-loop, delay, sleep

I am writing a script that gets an eight digit number then reads it out loud. I want a delay of two seconds between the numbers as they are being read out. The problem is that even after setting the delay with sleep(), all my numbers are read out at once which leads to a summon-like audio that is getting me closer to being the antichrist with every debug. Here is my code. How do i get my loop to execute so that the numbers are read as e.g 2 .... 1 .... 3 .... 4 .... (where .... = 2 seconds.)

```
for($counter=0; $counter<count($dbId); $counter++)
{
    $fileName = array_search($dbId[$counter], $letterArray);
    echo "<audio src='../resources/audio/mp3/'.$fileName.'.mp3' autoplay></audio>";
    echo time() . "<br />";
    sleep(2);
}
```

Comment: This question has been answered and as much as I am not supposed to say thanks in the comments section, its kind of hard to resist, "Thank you all".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an incorrect understanding of sleep. Sleep delays the php script, which delays the
response from the server, but the resulting webpage that you serve will be exactly the same
with or without sleep. It will just take longer to load. You can not control this from php
you have to do it on the client somehow. Look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11973673/have-audio-tag-play-after-a-delay) for example.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a hypertext pre processor. Meaning it's output cannot be send intermittently to the browser.

You have two options.

1. Create all `audio` elements without autoplay and handle your desired functionality with javascript using `setInterval`
2. Make a series of AJAX requests in order to get the next `audio` element enabling the autoplay feature. These requests can be fired by either listening for the `audio` to finish, or again using `setInterval`