# Autoplay sound mp3 each one minute

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

how can using php play a sound each 1 or 2 min

when a user enter in the page the first sound play

after 1 min another sound will be played and the first will be stopped of 
course all that will be auto play

html5 code:

```
<audio controls autoplay>
  <source src="horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11973673/have-audio-tag-play-after-a-delay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply you can merge both sound with your timing and implemented just like this:

```
<audio controls="controls" onloadeddata="audioSoundFunction()">
    <source src="horse.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
</audio>
```

**Javascript:**

```
function audioSoundFunction() {
  var audioSound = this; 
  setTimeout(function() { 
    audioSound.play(); 
  }, 10000)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<audio id="selecterForAudio" controls autoplay>
  <source src="horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

javascript/jquery

```
var myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 60000);
var audio = $("#selecterForAudio")[0];
var counter = 0;
var musicfiles = ["horse.mp3", "lard.mp3"];

function myTimer(){

   //stopping the audio
   audio.stop();
   //setting new source of array of sources
   $('#selecterForAudio').find('source').attr('src',musicfiles[counter]);
   counter+1;
   if(counter>COUNT(musicfiles)){
      counter=0;
   }
   //play sound
   audio.play();
}
```

something like this should fit your needs - it might need a little tweeking though